# How to solve 'unused args [old_kinect_frame]' problem?

Tags: ros, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow [pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps).

I run

```
 export ROBOT=sim
 roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch      pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
```

And I got:

```
 sam@sam:~$ export ROBOT=sim
 sam@sam:~$ roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch      pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
 ... logging to      /home/sam/.ros/log/d05d8cd2-8785-11e1-bf50-20cf30a23845/roslaunch-sam-1     6487.log
 Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
 Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
 
 unused args [old_kinect_frame] for include of      [/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/manipulation/pr2_object_m     anipulation_launch/launch/pr2_manipulation_prerequisites.launch]
 sam@sam:~$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31862/how-to-solve-%27unused-args-%5Bold_kinect_frame%5D%27-problem?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry!  That bug has been fixed in Electric-branch, but not in our released version yet.  I'll do a release today to fix it in debians.  In the meantime, you can get the updated launch file by doing
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/branches/0.5-branch/applications/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch/launch
and then just replace the one you're using.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0